# Spark Scala aggregation group Dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aggregate

I have input Dataframe and have to produce output Dataframe.
On input Dataframe, I have to group several columns and if that group has `sum` of another column some value for that group then I have to update one column for each member of that group with x.
So I will get several groups and have to update one of their columns with `x` and for rows that don’t get in any group value in that column must not be changed.

Like:

```
Job id , job name, department, age, old.
```

First 3 columns are grouped, `sum(age) = 100` then old gets `x` for all rows in group
And their will be several groups.
And output Dataframe will have same number of rows as input one.

val dfIn = job id , job name , department , age , old

```
     24        Dev         Sales       30    0
     24        Dev         Sales       40    0
     24        Dev         Sales       20    0
     24        Dev         Sales       10    0
     24        Dev         HR          30    0
     24        Dev         HR          20    0
     24        Dev         Retail      50    0
     24        Dev         Retail      50    0
```

val dfOut= job id , job name , department , age , old

```
     24        Dev         Sales       30    x
     24        Dev         Sales       40    x
     24        Dev         Sales       20    x
     24        Dev         Sales       10    x
     24        Dev         HR          30    0
     24        Dev         HR          20    0
     24        Dev         Retail      50    x
     24        Dev         Retail      50    x
```

Comment: I doubt that someone will answer this question if you do not give some input data sample and show the desired output.

Comment: Sorry, I was writing it on the go, I will provide data as soon as I get to computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just calculate `sum_age` using [Window function](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html) and use [`when/otherwise`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#when(org.apache.spark.sql.Column,%20java.lang.Object)) to affect `X` to `old` column when `sum_age = 100` otherwise keep same value `0`.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window  

val df = Seq(
       (24, "Dev", "Sales", 30, "0"), (24, "Dev", "Sales", 40, "0"),
       (24, "Dev", "Sales", 20, "0"), (24, "Dev", "Sales", 10, "0"),
       (24, "Dev", "HR", 30, "0"), (24, "Dev", "HR", 20, "0"),
       (24, "Dev", "Retail", 50, "0"), (24, "Dev", "Retail", 50, "0")
).toDF("job_id", "job_name", "department", "age", "old")


val w = Window.partitionBy($"job_id", $"job_name", $"department").orderBy($"job_id")
val dfOut = df.withColumn("sum_age", sum(col("age")).over(w))
             .withColumn("old", when($"sum_age" === lit(100), lit("X")).otherwise($"old"))
             .drop($"sum_age")


dfOut.show()

+------+--------+----------+---+---+
|job_id|job_name|department|age|old|
+------+--------+----------+---+---+
|    24|     Dev|        HR| 30|  0|
|    24|     Dev|        HR| 20|  0|
|    24|     Dev|    Retail| 50|  X|
|    24|     Dev|    Retail| 50|  X|
|    24|     Dev|     Sales| 30|  X|
|    24|     Dev|     Sales| 40|  X|
|    24|     Dev|     Sales| 20|  X|
|    24|     Dev|     Sales| 10|  X|
+------+--------+----------+---+---+
```